# OptionPane showmessage

Tags: java, joptionpane

I have made an Optionpane using the showmessage method now I can't seem to find out how to assign the "Ok" button and the exit button.
So I only want to close the JOptionPane and leave the frame untouched.
This is also my first time posting so if not everything is alright. I have also researched and cannot find the same question and/or answer anywhere.
I hope you guys can help me!

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            while((field1.getText().equals("")) || (field2.getText().equals("")) || (field3.getText().equals("")) || (field4.getText().equals("")) || (field5.getText().equals("")) || (field6.getText().equals("")) ){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "I find your lack of input disturbing.", "Input alert", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: Your code might run into infinite loop. Use `if` instead of `while`.

Comment: That was the issue thanks!

Comment: Remember to mark the answer that helped you as accepted! It will help future users understand what exactly fixed your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        if(field1.getText().equals("") && field2.getText().equals("") ...... N){
        JOptionpane......
        }
}
```

You should try this. instead of while loop.

Comment: Okay I fixed it. That was exactly what was wrong. I see now that that was the faulty code Thank you sir